# sharepoint 2010 calendar overlays across 2 web appllications

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-calendar

So I have two calendars on two different web applications. I want to take advantage of the calendar overlay option in sharepoint 2010.
cal1 on `http://intranet1` with service account (serviceaccount1)
cal2 on `http://intranet2` with a different service account (serviceaccount2)
Since they are two different web applications and different content databases, they also each have their own domain accounts that access it.

So when I tried to overlay cal2 from `http://intranet2` onto cal1 onto `http://intranet1`. I got an error. The logs show that the service account for `http://intranet1` could not access cal2 on `http://intranet2`. Failed to login into the content database for it.

So in my mind I would ask our database guys to allow serviceaccount1 read access to the content database for that web application (`http://intranet2`).

But is that the way to do it. Do I break something? Should I do it another way through central admin? Can I just "add" domian accounts to other web applications? Whats the best way?